# Kotlin libraries don't work in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I cant call `listOf()`. It is like kotlin libraries don't work.

[image]png

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you must delete `ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.31'`
and add last version (1.6.0) to the classpath

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.0"
```

and

check in module gradle to add to existing this lines:

```
plugins {

   id 'kotlin-kapt'

}

android{

    kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '1.8'
        }

}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'

}
```